# Verificacion de cuenta via email

Tags: laravel

Implemente la verificación de cuenta de usuarios via email, pero aun sin verificar el usuario puede iniciar sesión, he intentado evitarlo validando el campo confirmed de la tabla user (que por defecto es cero y cambia a uno cuando se verifica la cuenta) todo lo demás funciona de forma correcta, aca mi metodo authenticated del LoginController.

```
protected function authenticated($request, $user)
{
    if($user->confirmed == 1) {
        if($user->hasRole('Admin')) {
            return redirect()->intended('admin/index');
        }
        elseif ($user->hasRole('Tutor')) {
            return redirect()->intended('admin/index');
        }
    }
    else {
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción más adecuada sería sobreescibir el método login, para determinar si el usuario puede iniciar sesión o no antes de, y no después de, como lo estás haciendo en este caso.

¿Creo que trabajas con la versión 5.2? En esa versión este es el código que llama a la función authenticated:

```
/**
 * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  bool  $throttles
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function handleUserWasAuthenticated(Request $request, $throttles)
{
    if ($throttles) {
        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
    }

    if (method_exists($this, 'authenticated')) {
        return $this->authenticated($request, Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->user());
    }

    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Como puedes ver, es ejecutado después de la autenticación.

Otra opción más sencilla, pero menos recomendada, y que te funcionaría con el código actual sería hacer logout al momento de determinar que no ha sido verificado su correo:

```
protected function authenticated($request, $user)
{
    if($user->confirmed == 1) {
        if($user->hasRole('Admin')) {
            return redirect()->intended('admin/index');
        }
        elseif ($user->hasRole('Tutor')) {
            return redirect()->intended('admin/index');
        }
    }
    else {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

**Respuesta complementada por el OP basándose en los comentarios:**
Consegui bloquear el acceso sobreescribiendo el metodo login de esta forma:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    $validado = DB::table('users')->where('email', $request->email)->value('confirmed');

    if ($validado == 1) {
        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }
        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }

    }
    else {
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Uso la versión 5.4, el método login lo sobreescribiria en loginController.php? donde podria ver la función?

Comment: Exactamente, ahí iría, aquí puedes ver su código: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L22

Comment: Edite (ver en el post) el metodo login y logre bloquear el acceso,pero me gustaría introducir algunos mensajes en la pagina para indicar que el acceso se bloquea es por falta de confirmación y no como dice actualmente que es por que la cuenta no esta registrada, algun consejo para eso?

Comment: Eso lo puedes lograr pasando el mensaje a la sesión y obteniéndolo en el próximo request. Si consideras que la respuesta te fue útil, puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Si muchas gracias, la marcare como correcta, en cuanto al mensaje me podrias explicar un poco mas? no veo la forma de colocarlo en el metodo login ya que no redirecciono ahi hacia alguna ruta, entonces no veo como podria hacerlo mas o menos de esta forma: (ruta)->whith('status', 'Debe confirmar su cuenta, revise su email');